# Silex, bad credentials with security firewalls and custom user provider

Tags: php, silex

I have bad credentials on login attempt with security firewalls and custom user provider.
Here's my code.

```
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
        'security.firewalls' => array(
            'admin' => array(
                'pattern' => '^/admin',
                'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'),
                'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout'), // url to call for logging out
                'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                    // Specific class user\UserProvider
                    return new UserProvider();

                }),
            )
        ),
        'security.access_rules' => array(
            // You can rename ROLE_ADMIN as you wish
            array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
        )
    ));

    $app['security.encoder.digest'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
        // use the sha1 algorithm
        // don't base64 encode the password
        // use only 1 iteration
        return new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha1', false, 1);
    });
```

my route :

```
    $app->get("/login", "site\controllers\SiteController::login");
    $app->post("/admin/login_check", "admin\controllers\AdminController::loginCheck");
```

my sitecontroller function :

```
public function login(Application $app, Request $request) {
    return $app['twig']->render('site/views/login.html.twig', array(
        'error' => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
  }
```

my view :

```
<form action="{{ path('admin_login_check') }}" method="post">
    {{ error }}
    <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

my db table :

```
id  username    password    roles     
1   admin   d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997    ROLE_ADMIN
```

my custom user provider :

```
<?php
namespace user\models;
use app\config\PDOFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class UserProvider extends PDOFactory implements UserProviderInterface {

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {           
        $response = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
        $response->execute(array(strtolower($username)));
        if (!$user = $response->fetch()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
        }
        return new User($user['username'], $user['password'], explode(',', $user['roles']), true, true, true, true);
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User';
    }

}
```

my database connection :

```
namespace app\config;

abstract class PDOFactory {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {               
        $db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=silex', 'root', '');
        $db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

On login attempt, i don't think i access the loginCheck function from my admincontroller since it doesn't echo anything:

```
public function loginCheck(Application $app, Request $request) {
    echo 'LOGIN-CHECK';
    $username = $request->get('username');
    $password = $request->get('password');
    $password = $app['security.encoder.digest']->encodePassword($password, '');
    $userProvider = new UserProvider();
    $user = $userProvider->loadUserbyUsername($username);
    if ($user->getPassword() == $password){
        return $app['twig']->render('admin/views/index.html.twig');
    }
    else{
        return $app['twig']->render('site/views/login.html.twig', array(
            'error' => $app['security.last_error']($request),
            'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
        ));
    }
  }
```

my password is 'admin', i used this code to generate it for the database table:

```
echo $app['security.encoder.digest']->encodePassword('admin', '');
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Edit : 
my mistake was on my view, it didn't use the underscore before the post names

```
<form action="{{ path('admin_login_check') }}" method="post">
            {{ error }}
            <input type="text" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
            <input type="password" name="_password" value="" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```

And i don't need any route nor any controller function for the login_check path. It's managed by the security firewalls. 
Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, enable logging (via [monolog provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/monolog.html) and set `$app['debug'] = true;` and check the logs, the Security Component yells lots of information if logged is enabled.

Second, you don't have to create a controller (not even a route, the Security Provider [does it for you](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.2/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php#L387)) for the *check_path*, [the kernel traps all incoming request to this path](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php#L179) and [checks if the credentials are valid](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/SimpleFormAuthenticationListener.php#L101) (as long as you don't overwrite the default Authentication Provider, but you don't want to go that route just for using a login form).

Having said that and to debug your code you can try to [use the plain password encoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/PlaintextPasswordEncoder.php) and once this is working, change it back again (you'll need to update the password field on your db table, of course), but most likely the log will tell you what is happening (if you are still lost with the log, just post it also).